# CakePHP: How do I reference a flash asset in my plugin's webroot?

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-1.3

I'm using CakePHP to build a plugin and am trying to add a flash asset to my view.
The tag looks like this:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="unknown_url" id="VideoPlayback">
    <param name="movie" value="unknown_url" />
    <other params....>
</object>
```

Unfortunately I don't know what url to point to!
Given that my plugin is using standard structure (for CakePHP 1.3x) i would like to access my flash file which is stored here:

```
app/plugins/my_plugin/webroot/flash/my_flash_file.swf
```

I know that in the php side `/my_plugin/flash/my_flash_file.swf` gets rewritten to route correctly (this works just fine when I try something like `$this->Html->img('URL')` ), but I don't know of any Html Helper function to create object tags.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$this->Html->url()`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/helper#method-Helperurl) to create correct URLs.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<?php echo $this->Html->url( ' /my_plugin/flash/my_flash_file.swf' ); ?>" id="VideoPlayback">
    <param name="movie" value="<?php echo $this->Html->url( ' /my_plugin/flash/my_flash_file.swf' ); ?>" />
    <other params....>
</object>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is completely undocumented in the API (Though I did find it in the help-docs)!

Comment: The reason it's not mentioned in the HtmlHelper API is that the method is inherited from the Helper class, which makes it available in every helper.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $html->url('/webroot/uploadify/uploadify.swf');?>
```

it will give you link like `/your_app_name/webroot/uploadify/uploadify.swf`